# Multiple Java EE web apps in one host

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, host

How is it possible for a host to host multiple Java EE web applications?

Where I am doing my co-op, there is one app executing requests against this domain: subdomain.maindomain.com/foo/bar.htm

Another app is executing requests against this domain:
subdomain.maindomain.com/bar/foo.htmfirst, for example, handles all login authentications. The second handles registration.

Both are supposed to be Java EE web applications (or at least one is).

I'm a novice programmer, so hopefully you can understand what I'm referring to here.

Thanks for your help as I've tried to find a resource to explain this, but to no avail.

Comment: Your question is not clear: if *bar* and *foo* are deployed as separate applications on the same machine, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Different JavaEE applications can be co-hosted, with a few considerations while hosting, main consideration being the applications should have different context paths.

In the example you have provided, the urls have different context. While one application is having context as foo, the other is having bar.

See [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0405_poddar/0405_poddar.html) link for more details of hosting different versions of an application. I haven't gone through complete information but guess, you can apply same between different applications.